# jquery: hide/show div2 inside other div1 on mouseover

Tags: jquery

I have something like this:

```
<div id="wrap1">
<div id="util1">
</div>
bla bla
</div>

<div id="wrap2">
<div id="util2">
</div>
bla bla
</div>

<div id="wrap3">
<div id="util4">
</div>
bla bla
</div>

...
```

I need to show the **"util"** divs when cursor is over the **"wrap"** div and hide it back when cursor leaves the **"wrap"** div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div[id^=wrap]").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("div[id^=util]").show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find("div[id^=util]").hide();
});
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/hover/